# How to find and replace all occurrences of a string recursively in a directory tree?

Tags: sed, find, grep, replace

Using just grep and sed, how do I replace all occurrences of:

```
a.example.com
```

with

```
b.example.com
```

within a text file under the `/home/user/` directory tree recursively finding and replacing all occurrences in all files in sub-directories as well.

Answer (score 132):

Try this:

```bash
find /home/user/ -type f | xargs sed -i  's/a\.example\.com/b.example.com/g'
```

In case you want to ignore dot directories

```bash
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f | xargs sed -i 's/a\.example\.com/b.example.com/g'
```

Edit: escaped dots in search expression

Comment: Will this replace the string in every file under the /home/user directory?  Including sub-directories?

Comment: Yes it will, though you should specify some sort of pattern -name 'pattern' after find

Comment: what do you mean "some sort of pattern"?

Comment: A pattern like `-name 'pattern'` - where "pattern" might be like "domainlist*" - something that narrows down the search.

Comment: As per http://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282/477451, it's a good idea to use `-print0` and `-0` on the `find` and `xargs` commands respectively.

Comment: I would suggest updating the response with the above suggestions.  Hopefully that will lead to accept of this answer

Comment: in my case it searched and replaced in the whole system, even if i did type the directory. Why? Not that bad but it may not be so good in some other cases ...

Answer (score 48):

Try this:

```
grep -rl 'SearchString' ./ | xargs sed -i 's/REPLACESTRING/WITHTHIS/g'
```

`grep -rl` will recursively search for the `SEARCHSTRING` in the directories `./` and will replace the strings using `sed`.

Ex:

Replacing a name `TOM` with `JERRY` using search string as `SWATKATS` in directory `CARTOONNETWORK`

```
grep -rl 'SWATKATS' CARTOONNETWORK/ | xargs sed -i 's/TOM/JERRY/g'
```

This will replace `TOM` with `JERRY` in all the files and subdirectories under `CARTOONNETWORK` wherever it finds the string `SWATKATS`.

Comment: Thank you for this answer, and how to write it other files in order not to do mistakes ?

Comment: what does the `l` flag do in `-rl` ? Cause it's not working without it :)

Comment: `-l` prints the path to each file containing text that matches the pattern.

Answer (score 14):

On macOS, none of the answers worked for me. I discovered that was due to differences in how `sed` works on macOS and other BSD systems compared to GNU.

In particular BSD `sed` [takes the `-i` option but *requires a suffix for the backup* (but an empty suffix is permitted)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29083181/809944)

`grep` version from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38116261/809944).

```
grep -rl 'foo' ./ | LC_ALL=C xargs sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/g'
```

`find` version from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1585189/809944).

```
find . \( ! -regex '.*/\..*' \) -type f | LC_ALL=C xargs sed -i '' 's/foo/bar/g'
```

*Don't omit the Regex to ignore `.` folders if you're in a Git repo. I realized that the hard way!*

That `LC_ALL=C` option is to [avoid getting `sed: RE error: illegal byte sequence` if `sed` finds a byte sequence that is not a valid UTF-8 character](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23584470/809944). That's another difference between BSD and GNU. Depending on the kind of files you are dealing with, you may not need it.

For some reason that is not clear to me, the `grep` version found more occurrences than the `find` one, which is why I recommend to use `grep`.

Answer (score 7):

I know this is a really old question, but...

1. @vehomzzz's answer uses `find` and `xargs` when the questions says explicitly `grep` and `sed` only.
2. @EmployedRussian and @BrooksMoses tried to say it was a dup of `awk` and `sed`, but it's not - again, the question explicitly says `grep` and `sed` *only*.

So here is my solution, assuming you are using Bash as your shell:

```
OLDIFS=$IFS
IFS=$'\n'
for f in `grep -rl a.example.com .` # Use -irl instead of -rl for case insensitive search
do
    sed -i 's/a\.example\.com/b.example.com/g' $f # Use /gi instead of /g for case insensitive search
done
IFS=$OLDIFS
```

If you are using a different shell, such as Unix SHell, let me know and I will try to find a syntax adjustment.

*P.S.: Here's a one-liner:*

```
OLDIFS=$IFS;IFS=$'\n';for f in `grep -rl a.example.com .`;do sed -i 's/a\.example\.com/b.example.com/g' $f;done;IFS=$OLDIFS
```

Sources:

- [Bash: Iterating over lines in a variable](https://superuser.com/questions/284187/bash-iterating-over-lines-in-a-variable)
- [grep(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep)
- [Official Grep Manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/grep.html)
- [sed(1) - Linux man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/sed)
- [Official sed Manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.txt)

Comment: Sed supports using an alternate character separator like `%` that isn't common in URLs so you don't have to escape all the slashes.

Comment: @dragon788 I did not know that, however I wasn't escaping the forward slashes. I was escaping the periods. A period is a regex special character for any character, thus it has to be escaped to match specifically the period in a domain name.

Answer (score 5):

For me works the next command:

```
find /path/to/dir -name "file.txt" | xargs sed -i 's/string_to_replace/new_string/g'
```

if string contains slash 'path/to/dir' it can be replace with another character to separate, like '@' instead '/'.

For example:  `'s@string/to/replace@new/string@g'`

Answer (score 5):

We can try using the more powerful ripgrep as

```sh
rg "BYE_BYE_TEXT" ./ --files-with-matches | xargs sed -i "s/BYE_BYE_TEXT/WELCOME_TEXT/g"
```

Because ripgrep is good at finding and sed is great at replacing.

Comment: Is there an option to make this work under windows as well (git bash if you're wondering)? `rg` keeps using backslashes, sed does not like that (mostly omits them since none matches to an escape code in my case, I guess) and fails with _No such file or directoy_. I _could_ `sed` the backlashes to slashes but an `rg` options would make things easier in general.

For now I use `rg "inpattern" ./ --files-with-matches |  sed "s|\\\|/|g" | xargs sed -i  -b "s/inpattern/outpattern/g" ` - (`-b`/binary mode to keep your line endings as they are).

Answer (score 3):

it is much simpler than that.

```sh
for i in `find *` ; do sed -i -- 's/search string/target string/g' $i; done
```

`find i` => will iterate over all the files in the folder and in subfolders.

`sed -i`  => will replace in the files the relevant string if exists.

Answer (score 2):

Try this command:

```
/home/user/ directory - find ./ -type f \
-exec sed -i -e 's/a.example.com/b.example.com/g' {} \;
```

Comment: Hello. Please don't just dump code as an answer. Explain what you are doing so users can understand how to solve the problem. Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

The command below will search all the files recursively whose name matches the search pattern and will replace the string:

`find /path/to/searchdir/ -name "serachpatter" -type f | xargs sed -i  's/stringone/StrIngTwo/g'`

Also if you want to limit the depth of recursion you can put the limits as well:

`find /path/to/searchdir/ -name "serachpatter" -type f -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 2 | xargs sed -i  's/stringone/StrIngTwo/g'`

Comment: find /path/to/searchdir/ -name "serachpatter" -type f -maxdepth 4 -mindepth 2 | xargs sed -i 's/stringone/StrIngTwo/g'

Comment: In the future, please edit your answer instead of posting a comment beneath it. Also, please format code appropriate; do not use bold formatted text for code.