# Grunt file output static assets point to specified URL

Tags: javascript, static, gruntjs

In my index file, I have something like this:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) scripts/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/foo.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bar.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

Which then outputs to my dist like this:

```
<script src="scripts/cce9cd3a.main.js"></script>
```

What I'm trying to do is modify the way the dist is rendered so it says something like:

```
<script src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/etc/etc/static/scripts/cce9cd3a.main.js"></script>
```

The idea is I want it to output to the dist folder in the same way, which I will move over to s3. What is a clean way to prepend all of my static assets to the same static serve url using grunt?

Comment: Is this because you're serving the resulting .js via AWS while the rest of the page is elsewhere?

Comment: @MattBakaitis yup, exactly what's happening.

Comment: ...but grunt isn't pushing the file to AWS and the AWS path will be constant except for the filename.  Correct?

Comment: correct, I'll either get the files to aws with another build script or just move it over manually as I'm doing now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based upon the discussion we had in comments, you have two general options after `grunt-usemin` does it's work.

**1) Find-and-replace from the shell.**

If you are using a *nix system with grep and similar tools, you can put the file someplace easy to `grep` and replace.  For example, you could change your build blocks to something like:

```
<!-- build:js({.tmp,app}) awsreplacepath/main.js -->
    <script src="scripts/foo.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/bar.js"></script>
<!-- endbuild -->
```

so you get something like:

```
<script src="awsreplacepath/cce9cd3a.main.js"></script>
```

Then use a grep-and-replace shell script, like the one discussed in these questions to replace the `awsreplacepath` with the path to want referenced.

- [How to grep and replace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15402770/how-to-grep-and-replace)
- [How to find and replace all occurrences of a string recursively in a directory tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1585170/how-to-find-and-replace-all-occurrences-of-a-string-recursively-in-a-directory-t?rq=1)

**2) Find-and-replace before grunt finishes.**

There are a few find-and-replace plugins for grunt, but [grunt-string-replace](https://github.com/erickrdch/grunt-string-replace) seems to have the most usage according to npmjs.org.

This isn't really much different than the first option.

In both cases, the regex should be simple as you can pick a string that is essentially certain to be unique...so you won't need to do much more than drop something like 'awsreplacepath' into the regex.

...and just remember that the `main.js` file usemin generated and that you need to move will still be in the `awsreplacepath` directory.  All we're doing is changing the HTML to prevent you from having to edit the file yourself.

Comment: It would be more robust to use the [grunt.filerev.summary](https://github.com/yeoman/grunt-filerev) hash rather than a regex.

Comment: I don't work a ton with grunt, so fall back to things I know and have used in similar situations.  If you have a working example along that line, I'd appreciate seeing it.