# sed: 1: "...": Invalid command code f

Tags: sed

```
grep -l \'texttofind\' * | xargs sed -i 's/toreplace/replacewith/g'
```

Im getting this error when I run the above command in the terminal.

```
sed: 1: "forkliftDailyChecklistW ...": invalid command code f
```

I've looked at several forums and have found nothing about code f.
Any help/insight would be appreciated

Comment: Please show the exact sed command you're using (instead of `toreplace` and `replacewith`). Wildly guessing: is there a `/` in one of the terms?

Comment: Yes. Assuming the output of `grep`is correct you should definitely check for `/` in the arguments of `sed`. If this is the case, try using the syntax `'s_toreplace_replacewith_g'`.

Comment: Here's the command: grep -l \'/usr/local/www/apache22/data/htconfig/dbconfigure.php\' * | xargs sed -i 's/\/usr\/local\/www\/apache22\/data/'\''\.\$_SERVER\['\''DOCUMENT_ROOT'\''\]\.'\''/g'

Answer (score 94):

I figured out what was wrong. I needed to add `''` after the `-i` and before the `'s/../../'`:

```
grep -l \'texttofind\' * | xargs sed -i '' 's/toreplace/replacewith/g'
```

Comment: I knew lunch would fix it!

Comment: You are probably running on a Mac, or a BSD system.  The BSD `sed` command takes the `-i` option but requires a suffix for the backup (but an empty suffix is permitted).  Providing basic platform information often helps.