# Crop Lines from multiple CSV files using bash

Tags: bash, csv, awk, sed

I have a directory of 40 or so csv's. Each csv file has an extra 10 lines at the top that I don't need. I'm new to bash commands, but I have found that I can use

```
tail -n +10 oldfile.csv > newfile.csv
```

to cut 10 lines from a file one at a time. How can I do this across all csv's in the directory? I have tried doing this:

```
for filename in *foo*; do echo tail -n +10 \"$filename\" > \"${filename}\"; done
```

From what I've read, I thought this would pass in every csv containing *foo* in its name, run the formula, and leave the filename alone. Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a proper loop as below. Am using the native `ex` editor which `Vim` uses internally to in-place replacement, so you don't have to move the files back again using `mv` or any other command.

```
for file in *.csv
do
    ex -sc '1d10|x' "$file"
done
```

The command moves to first line, selects 10 lines from first, deletes it and saves & closes the file.

Use a command-line friendly version in a single line as

```
for file in *.csv; do ex -sc '1d10|x' "$file"; done
```

The `ex` command is [`POSIX` compatible](http://www.unix.com/man-page/posix/1p/ex/) and can work on all major platforms and distros.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot use the same file as input and ouput.

With sed, your can edit the file *in place*  with the `-i` flag:

```
for f in *.csv; do
    sed -i '1,10d' "$f"
done
```

or as one-liner for the command line:

```
for f in *.csv; do sed -i '1,10d' "$f"; done
```

As a side note, your `tail` should be `tail -n +11` to output 11th line to end of file.

Comment: Getting an "invalid command code" error when I run this. The way I'm running this is by 'cd' to the directory, for f in *.csv; do [Enter], >sed -i '1,10d' "$f" [Enter], > done [Enter].. back to $.. then I get invalid command code

Comment: Multiline is more for scripts. I added a one-liner for the command line.

Comment: Works! But... had to add '' in between -i and '1,10d'.. credit: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29081799/sed-1-invalid-command-code-f (I'm on a Mac). Final: for f in *.csv; do sed -i '' '1,10d' "$f"; done

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
$ awk 'FNR>10{ print > "new-" FILENAME }' files*
```

Explained:

- `FNR>10` if *current record number in current file* is greater than 10, condition is true.
- `print` well, output
- `> "new-" FILENAME` redirect output to a new file named `new-file`, for example.

**Edited** to writing output to multiple files. Original which just outputed to screen was `awk 'FNR>10' files*`

Comment: But does it save it to the file?