# How do I do a recursive find & replace within an SVN checkout?

Tags: command-line, replace

How do I find and replace every occurrence of:

```
foo
```

with

```
bar
```

in every text file under the /my/test/dir/ directory tree (recursive find/replace).

BUT I want to be able to do it safely within an SVN checkout and not touch anything inside the .svn directories

Similar to this but now with the SVN restriction: [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string/1583229#1583229)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There are several possiblities:

**Using find:**

Using find to create a list of all files, and then piping them to `sed` or the equivalent, as suggested in the answer you reference, is fairly straightforward, and only requires scanning through the files once.

You'd use one of the same answers as from the question you referenced, but adding `-path '*/.svn' -prune -o` after the `find .` in order to prune out the SVN directories.  See [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/207034/why-doesnt-find-prune-the-way-i-think-it-should) for a discussion of using the `prune` option with `find` -- although note that they've got the pattern wrong.  Thus, to print out all the files, you would use:

```
find . -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -print
```

Then, you can pipe that into an `xargs` call or whatever to do the individual replacements, as suggested in the question you referenced.  There is a lot of discussion there about different options, which I won't reproduce here, although I prefer the version from [John Zwinck's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string/1585810#1585810):

```
find . -path '*/.svn' -prune -o -type f -exec sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' {} +
```

**Using recursive grep:**

If you have a system with GNU grep, you can use that to find the list of files as well.  This is probably less efficient than find, but it does allow you to only call `sed` on the files that match, and I personally find the syntax a lot easier to remember (or figure out from manpages):

```
sed -i 's/foo/bar/g' `grep -l -R --exclude-dir='*/.svn' 'foo' .`
```

The `-l` option causes grep to only output the list of file names, rather than the matching lines.

**Using a GUI editor:**

Alternately, if you're using windows, do what I do -- get a copy of the NoteTab editor (available in a free version), and use its search-and-replace-on-disk command, which ignores hidden .svn directories automatically and just works.

**Edit:** Corrected find pattern to `*/.svn` instead of `.svn`, added more details and some other possibilities.  However, this depends on your platform and svn version: `.svn` without `*/` may be required in some cases, like on CentOS 7.

Comment: I think you're saying to do this:

    find . -path '.svn' -prune -o -type f -print

But that doesn't seem to work.

Comment: That is what I was saying to do -- and, you're right, it doesn't work.  I think I've figured out why, and will edit to correct.

Comment: When I do the recursive grep on CentOS 7, I still get .svn directories.  If I instead put `--exclude-dir='.svn'` they go away.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
grep -i "search_string" `find "*.some_extension"`
```

That is halfway solution to finding a `search_string` within files that have a specific extension....once you know the files that has the string, can be easily modified by piping it into sed....

Comment: That seems like a very complicated way of doing `grep -R -i "search_string"`, and in either case you need to add something to exclude the SVN directories.

Comment: @Brooks: its a more portable version to use since not all grep has a recursive switch....