# BASH: recursive program to replace text in a tree of files

Tags: bash, recursion, replace

I am completely new at Bash but I just can't seem to find a way to make it do what I want.

Imagine you have a tree directory with 2 files:
/top.php and /test/bottom.php

How do I make my function look and replace say "hello" into "bonjour" in /top.php AND in /test/bottom.php?

So far the only way I have found to do this is by calling the same function twice with a different depth level:

```
find ./*.php -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/' {} \;
find ./*/*.php -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/' {} \;
```

Surely there's a recursive way to do this in one line?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Use an actual pattern for find instead of shell wildcard expansion:

```
find . -name '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/' {} \;
```

Comment: Yours worked perfect! I'd upvote it if I could but I don't have the required amount of reputation yet

Comment: @Erken: Thanks. You should have the reputation to accept the answer (the checkmark below the number of votes). Which is the correct response if it works, anyway :-).

Comment: Perfect, got it! Thanks a lot you guys, you've been amazingly fast!! oO

Comment: Thanks. This is helping get bsdgames built under cygwin.

Comment: How can i see the log of this command to make sure everything went fine?

Answer (score 2):

Close:

```
find -iname '*.php' -type f -exec sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/' {} \;
```

Or

```
find -iname '*.php' -type f -print0 |
     xargs -0 sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/'
```

Comment: the first solution you gave didn't work. I haven't tried the second one but the solution given by thiton was more straight forward

Comment: @Erken: that is because you had more files in the top directory than the question described. Learn to quote your wildcards if you don't want them expanded.

Answer (score -2):

Use xargs and grep:

```
find . -type f | grep php$ | xargs -n1 -i sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/' {}
```

Here's how it works:

Find all files in-and-below current directory:

```
find . -type f
```

Include just those files ending in php:

```
grep php$
```

Take each line and apply sed to it:

```
xargs -n1 -i sed -i 's/hello/bonjour/' {}
```

Comment: First of all, don't put spaces in your filenames! :) Secondly, just quote-enclose the "{}" portion and you should be ok.

Comment: Nope. Grep/xargs will kill your kittens.

Comment: @StephenGross: No, actually. The problem is with xargs and its concept of a delimiter.

Comment: Ah, good point. Well, in that case, my first recommendation stands: Don't put spaces in your filenames.

Comment: @StephenGross: A more unworkable piece of advice I've never heard. How about just writing good shell code?

Comment: @Sorpigal I was just kidding :)