# List files in local Git repo?

Tags: git

I'm using SparkleShare, which uses Git to sync files between my laptop and my backup server.

Now I want to be able to browse the files and dirs that I've uploaded to my server, but I do not know how.

I understand that Git uses some sort of special file hierarchy and that I cannot just list my files, right?

But what would I have to do to list them and browse my files?

Comment: Flagged as duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15606955/how-can-i-make-git-show-a-list-of-the-files-that-are-being-tracked/69869399 even though this question is older, as the other one is more clearly phrased and has more answers so SO stays tidy

Answer (score 642, accepted):

This command:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only HEAD
```

lists all of the already committed files being tracked by your git repo.

Comment: This works only when we have at least one commit.

Comment: This is the ***universal answer*** as it works in all the *realms* of `git`: **repository**, **index** & **working tree** [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76797811/22595851). Which makes this a great answer... but my goodness - three (3) options to get a file list?!

Answer (score 398):

Try this command:

```
git ls-files
```

This lists all of the files in the repository, including those that are only staged but not yet committed.

http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-files.html

Comment: Same output as the answer above, but with --name-only (Short format). Nice porcelain.

Comment: This Git command makes a much cleaner output and is ideal if you just want the list of files tracked by Git.

Comment: is there a way to list only direcotries.. something like `git ls-directories`  ?

Comment: **Warning:** if you are in a subdirectory, it only lists files under that tree - the question states "all of the files in the repository" but that's only true if you're in the root of the repo.

Comment: With git 2.6.12 I need `-r HEAD` to get any output from `git ls-files` without an error, even the subtree. I agree the accepted answer is better to recurse from the top.

Comment: I've used `git ls-files --full-name :/`. `:/` means the root directory of the repository, while `--full-name` outputs paths relative to the root directory of the repository rather than the working directory.

Comment: And to list just the tracked files from a certain directory: `git ls-files some/dir`.

Comment: @TreborRude works fine on a bare repo for me:
Inside the bare repo: `git ls-files`
Outside I just need to specify location of the repo (the same way I need to for any git command) `git --git-dir=$HOME/.dotfiles.git/ ls-files`. Maybe things have changed since you wrote that?

Comment: I get nothing from this command. I'm in the root dir of a git server repo. Amazing that an incorrect answer can get so many votes.

Answer (score 5):

`git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD` and `git ls-files` return all files at once. For a large project with hundreds or thousands of files, and if you are interested in a particular file/directory, you may find more convenient to explore specific directories. You can do it by obtaining the ID/SHA-1 of the directory that you want to explore and then use `git cat-file -p [ID/SHA-1 of directory]`. For example:

```
git cat-file -p 14032aabd85b43a058cfc7025dd4fa9dd325ea97
100644 blob b93a4953fff68df523aa7656497ee339d6026d64    glyphicons-halflings-regular.eot
100644 blob 94fb5490a2ed10b2c69a4a567a4fd2e4f706d841    glyphicons-halflings-regular.svg
100644 blob 1413fc609ab6f21774de0cb7e01360095584f65b    glyphicons-halflings-regular.ttf
100644 blob 9e612858f802245ddcbf59788a0db942224bab35    glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff
100644 blob 64539b54c3751a6d9adb44c8e3a45ba5a73b77f0    glyphicons-halflings-regular.woff2
```

In the example above, `14032aabd85b43a058cfc7025dd4fa9dd325ea97` is the ID/SHA-1 of the directory that I wanted to explore. In this case, the result was that four files within that directory were being tracked by my Git repo. If the directory had additional files, it would mean those extra files were not being tracked. You can add files using `git add <file>...` of course.

Comment: You could also just `cd` to the directory that you're interested in and omit `--full-tree`.

Comment: @Nathan will that still work with bare repos or whenever the worktree is entirely elsewhere? The question was about repo not worktree after all.

Answer (score 0):

The [selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8533413/22595851) worked fine for me, but it's rather *verbose*, and difficult (for me) to remember. I use this instead - which is a bit more detailed in its output, but easier to recall:

```bash
$ git ls-tree HEAD
100644 blob 8f9750a30099657bf8cdb303b128af91a41af96e    file1.c
100755 blob 7d61d074a6671622f34bd281925d56d5b62265e0    file2.h
100755 blob 6a1bf1c562f03d7526126261b030f560feab23a5    file3.8
```