# How to get list of all the files Git knows about (on Windows)

Tags: windows, git

I'm trying to get a list of all the files that have been checked into a Git repository. Unfortunately, all the solutions I can find to this assume Linux (or similar), but I'm using Windows. How do I do it from a Windows shell?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files in local git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo)

Answer (score 0):

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
```

see [List files in local git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo)

hth