# git ls-files in bare repository

Tags: git, git-bare, git-ls-files

I want to access a bare git repository, and I want to list all files in the repository.

On a normal git repository I can easily do that by running `git ls-files`.

Example output:

```
$ git ls-files
README.md
file1.js
file2.js
file3.js
folder1/file4.js
folder2/file5.js
```

In a bare git repository this fails silently. It just doesn't return any files (but exits successfully):

```
$ cd my-bare-repository
$ git ls-files #returns nothing
$ echo $? #print exit code from previous command
$ 0
```

Now I am aware that I have to provide a meaningful branch or master to display. But how can I actually get this list of the files that I know are in my repository?

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You can try the other command which list files:

```
git ls-tree --full-tree -r HEAD
```

According [to this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo#comment39711737_14406253), the command [git ls-tree](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-tree) works in **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24115534/6309)**.

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, in my current example, I get the same output with and without `--full-tree`

Comment: @JesperRønn-Jensen you also have `git ls-tree --full-tree -r --name-only HEAD` , to list just the file names, (without leading cruft about permissions and blob SHA values)

Comment: I am accepting this answer since it's more than I asked for:) +10 for correctness, +10 for fast answer :)

Comment: `git ls-files` works for me in a bare repository with git 2.27, and probably has supported it for a while now.

Comment: @VictorRoetman Yes: it could list files in the index. by default (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-ls-files) And technically, a bare repository can have an index (https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2sharp/issues/1491#issuecomment-328624372). But in my bare repos, `git ls-files` returns nothing.