# Determine the URL of a remote repository

Tags: git

I have been provided the login details (username and password to connect through SSH) to a web server.
It contains a web application that I am supposed to submit some regular updates via git.
The server is access via its IP address and I can't connect to it via HTTP requests.
I ran the `git init` command inside the root directory (public_html/app) of the web application.

I need to add it as a remote repository but I do not know how:
I tried the following:

```
git remote add APP user@209.32.x.x:public_html/app/app.git
```

and then

```
git clone user@209.32.x.x:public_html/app/app.git
```

But I get

```
fatal: repository 'APP' does not exist
```

**I am new to git.**

first: What do I need to make the `app` directory a git repo?

second: how to determine what the link of the repo is? (What to clone?)

Comment: Talk to whoever gave you the login details and find out **if** there is a git repository for this application and **where** this is. A normal web server does not serve git properly, nor does most web applications come with all their source files.

Comment: well they say application and git are now working in the server and I just need to convert it into a repository.

Comment: There's no conversion involved. Either they gave you a valid URL to connect to or not. `git remote add` doesn't do anything except associate a name with a URL; it doesn't attempt to make any sort of initial connection to the URL.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use the absolute path for the folder:

```
 user@209.32.x.x:/path/to/public_html/app
```

If you have done a `git init` within `public_html/app`, you don't need to add an "app.git".
But you do need to add [`git config receive.denycurrentbranch updateInstead`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28262104/6309) if you want to be able to push directly to a non-bare repo.

Another approach is to set up a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/6309)** (which would be more in line with your `app.git`) folder, and push to it (no receive config needed in that case), with a post-receive hook which will then checkout the latest pushed commit to your site:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root/.git --work-tree=/path/to/public_html/app checkout -f
```

In both case, the question remains: do you have a git repo with the site content history?