# Push to local virtual server

Tags: git, git-push, git-remote

How do I set up git so that it will push to a local remote server? Say I run a vmware server in the other room. I have the IP and root access to the server in this case. I want to be able to push to it then have it deploy to the live production based off this push. IE I want a git remote of say "localdev" and "localpro" for dev and production. The "localpro" should be my folder I serve the webpages from.

This make any sense or am I just lost in my own little world of dreams?

Comment: `git daemon` can setup a very simple git server. You can google solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need a listener for your git push ([git daemon](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Git-Daemon), or [Apache](https://gist.github.com/oodavid/1809044), or [SSH](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-on-the-Server-Setting-Up-the-Server))
You can also consider a Git repo hosting service like [gogs.io](https://gogs.io/), very simple to install: just copy one executable.

In any case, you will manage **[bare repos](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/6309)**, to which you can add a [post-receive hook](https://git-scm.com/book/gr/v2/Customizing-Git-Git-Hooks#_server_side_hooks) with a line like:

```
git --git-dir=/path/to/project_root/.git --work-tree=/path/to/localpro checkout -f
```