# Cannot get my github to branch "fatal error work tree"

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, github

For this project I am remote from both instances (from home)and using PuTTY with SSH

`$school` = School

`$aws` = Amazon web service (instance running Puppet)

`$school` git created using `git init --bare githubdir`

```
branches  config  description  HEAD  hooks  info  objects  refs
```

`$aws` git created using

```
Mkdir githubdir && cd githubdir
git init
git remote add origin studentID@$school:githubdir
```

- I need to push from `$school` to `$aws` that is running Puppet to execute code from `$school`
- I need to submit work from `$school`

I have successfully pushed from `$school` to `$aws` but I wanted to setup branches for version control, however I get fatal error on `$school`:

```
[studentID@$school githubdir]$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
[studentID@$school githubdir]$ git branch
* master
  v1
[studentID@$school githubdir]$ git checkout master
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
[studentID@$school githubdir]$
[studentID@$school githubdir]$ git log
commit  3abd0c361ee*********
Author: Ben*** <studentID@$school>
Date:   Date

    first commit to the repo test
```

I can branch/checkout etc fine on `$aws`:

```
[awsUser@$aws githubdir]$ git status
# On branch master
nothing to commit, working directory clean
[awsUser@$aws githubdir]$ git branch
* master
[awsUser@$aws githubdir]$ git checkout master
Already on 'master'
[awsUser@$aws githubdir]$ git log
commit  3abd0c361ee*********
Author: Ben*** <studentID@$school>
Date:   Date

    first commit to the repo test
[awsUser@$aws githubdir]$ ls
firstFile
[awsUser@$aws githubdir]$
```

Have I got my understanding incorrect of flow? I was instructed to set up this way, but it seems that I have been told to write in `$aws` and push to `$school`?

**Note:** You are not giving me a solution to any assignment or graded type questions, this is purely an issues I am having with the environment and possibly the flow of execution?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

Here's a simple model. `$school` is for storage only. `$aws` is for production only although it's possible to make changes and commits here. `$local` is for development. Every contributor can have one or more local repositories.

A work tree is a field where files are checked out and placed. For production and development you need a work tree, so these repoistories are created as non-bare repositories. For storage, the work tree is not necessary and a bare repository is enough. Some commands need a work tree, like `git checkout`, and others don't, like `git log`.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed model, it helped me visualize it a lot better than a lot of the written documents!

Answer (score 1):

> but it seems that I have been told to write in $aws and push to $school?

Yes: you are supposed to push to a **[bare repo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/6309)** (ie a repo without a working tree, without the actual files)

That is why you see errors like

```
[studentID@$school githubdir]$ git status
fatal: This operation must be run in a work tree
```