# GitKraken refuses to open local repository if directory is named <something>.git -- any workaround?

Tags: git, gitkraken

I name my local repository folders `project_name.git`.

GitKraken does not like this convention.
Local repositories stored in directory with `.git` suffix fail to open (the same repo works if i drop the `.git` suffix).

I have dozens of repositories locally, I'm not gonna rename them all.
But i would love to keep using GitKraken, it's great.

Did anyone bump into this issue and find a workaround?

(I created a support ticket with them weeks ago, and never got an answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`project_name.git` generally is the naming convention for [bare repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38002059/6309) (repos without checked out files in a working tree, just the Git database).

That might be why GitKraken refuses to open such repositories: no working tree to work with.

Without renaming your folder, you might try, for testing, a symlink `project_name` (which is posible even on Windows) to the `project_name.git` folder, and see if GitKraken accepts to open `project_name`

Comment: How did i not think of this? Thank you!