# How does one push a local git repo to a remote git server?

Tags: git

For my work, I have been tasked with seeing if git (not github) will be a solid version control system for our project. I'm just trying to get a sense of how it works right now. I have never used git before besides a compsci class many moons ago in which we used a gui and github.

What I have done so far (besides install git on both machines):

**Initialized a bare repo on the server**

```
mkdir /path/to/test.git
cd /path/to/test.git
git init --bare test.git
```

**Created a repo on local machine**

```
mkdir testGitProject
cd testGitProject
git init
```

**Prepared my "project"**

```
*made some random txt files (1, 2, & 3)*
git add 1 
git add 2
git add 3
git commit -m "Initial commit, testing with three txt files"
```

**Added remote server to local machine**
This is where I believe I started making mistakes

```
git remote add origin ssh://user@<remote_server_ip>/path/to/test.git
```

**Attempt to push to remote server**

```
git push origin master
```

I had to sign in with my ssh password and the output on my local machine indicated everything was "pushed" successfully. I tried to recreate this output but now all I see when running a push is "Everything up-to-date." I would also like to note I followed [this walkthrough](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/git-push-local-code-to-live-linux-server/) to create a "post-receive" hook on my local machine - not sure if that matters.

Looking at various walkthroughs and forum posts, I get very confused about live, origin, and master. I am not sure if this is just based on what you named your branches/remotes or if I need to understand them better. Both "branches" directories (on local repo and remote repo) are empty, which I assumed I'd see something there.

I feel like I understand how 65% of git works, and the other 35% I'm clueless on. I was hoping to see the three text files in my remote repo, but don't see them even when running find commands. Was this process at least somewhat close to what I need to be doing?

Comment: You pushed successfully. That part is done. Ok. Now you need to understand what is bare repo. See https://stackoverflow.com/q/5540883/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/q/37992400/7976758 and https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+what+bare+repository

Answer (score 1):

`origin` is the default name ofr a remote repository URL.
But in your [tutorial](https://www.codingforentrepreneurs.com/blog/git-push-local-code-to-live-linux-server/), the remote URL is registered and referenced as "`live`".

That is because a simple `git push` would push, by default, to "`origin`".
However, updating the **live** server (which, as its name suggests, represents the live visible-to-all website) should be an explicit action.
By using a non-default remote name (`live`), you make sure a change to the live server needs more than `git push`: it needs `git push live`, making sure the user *wants* to impact the live server.

Since the push is done to a [bare repository](https://www.saintsjd.com/2011/01/what-is-a-bare-git-repository/), it needs a post-receive hook to checkout the content of what has been pushed to the actual live website folder.

Hence the `/var/repo/myproject.git/hooks/post-receive` executable script with:

```
git --work-tree=/var/www/myproject/ --git-dir=/var/repo/myproject.git/ checkout -f
```

By pushing to the bare repository, you trigger the post-receive hook which, in turn, update the `/var/www/myproject/` folder.

Comment: Thank you so much, for a stranger to put that much effort in helping is awesome

Comment: @YahBoyDontKnowGit No problem, let me know if that answers fully your question, or if I need to add more details.