# List all files in a given remote GIT repository and branch

Tags: git

Need to List all the files avaialble in a given remote GIT repository and branch?

Please help with commands..

Comment: `git ls-tree -r <branch_name>` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [List files in local git repo?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo)

Comment: I need to have a single command to list all the folders available in a given remote GIT repository and branch...

Answer (score 9):

If you want to list all files for a specific branch, e.g. master:

```
git ls-tree -r master --name-only
```

Comment: Thanks. I need to have a single command to list all the folders available in a given remote GIT repository and branch...

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, which specifically refers to a *remote* git repo. So the solution should take a URL instead of a tree-ish as an argument.