# How to find git committed files list on origin?

Tags: git

I would like to check all committed files from multiple commits on `origin/master` branch.

I have been checking following commands all are working on local branches only but not working on origin/master because they checking against origin/master only.

- `git diff master...<branch>`,
- `git diff master... --name-only`,
- `git diff HEAD origin/master --name-only`,
- `git whatchanged/log --name-only --pretty="" origin..HEAD`

How to can do the same operation on `origin/master`?

I am directly making changes on origin/master branch then commit the files. It can be multiple commits. Now, I would like to know what are all the files that I changed on master branch.

Comment: I'm not clear what you're looking for here, and what you mean by "checking against origin/master only" - what do you want it to check against instead? Perhaps you could [edit] your question to include an example of the steps you go through (creating a branch, changing some files, etc), and the output you want to see? Make sure you include details of how the output you want is different from the output you get with the commands you've tried.

Comment: I am directly changing master branch only. So, before I push my changes I would like to find the list.

Comment: What do you mean by _the list_?

Comment: @Clijsters committed files.

Comment: What's the problem with `git diff HEAD..origin/master`?

Comment: I do not know why somebody gave down vote.

Comment: @Rekha: I think, because the most users don't understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I would like to check all committed files from multiple commits before
>   I push on origin/master branch.

**GITK approach**

One easy approach for you is using `gitk`, if you don't have gitk install the gitk in your system, go to your master.

`git checkout master` and then start `gitk` from the origin you will see the list of committed files in the master.

---

**Method 2: Without gitk.**

If you don't want to use gitk then another approach to list the commited files in branch. For master first you switch to the origin master issuing,

```
git checkout master
git show --pretty="" --name-only <sha>
```

Comment: Thanks for  your reply. `git show --pretty="" --name-only` will show only lastest commit. What if I have multiple commits. I am changing master branch directly and would like find the files which are committed.

Comment: for all commit better I suggest you to use gitk that is user friendly for the beginners.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing master branch directly"? Also, would [this question/answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo) help?