# list all tracked files in every branch

Tags: git

I know one can use `git ls-tree` to [list all tracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8533202/list-files-in-local-git-repo) in a given branch.
Is there an efficient way to list all tracked files *in all branches*?

One can of course write a small script like:

```
#!/bin/bash
(
  for b in $(git branch --no-color|tr '*' ' '|tr -s " "|cut -d " " -f 2)
  do
     git ls-tree -r "${b}" --name-only
  done
)| sort | uniq
```

This seems however rather inefficient when there are many branches, and especially if, as usual, most files are tracked in all branches.

Is there a more efficient way to list all tracked files?

Answer (score 1):

The trouble is that Git has no notion of "all tracked files"; the very idea is meaningless. Git's notion is exactly the notion expressed by `ls-tree`: for *any given commit* (or other tree-ish object), what files does it contain?

Well, this is something that Git can do, obviously, for *any* tree-ish. It happens that *you* are interested in only those tree-ish object that are commits that have branch names pointing at them. So there is no "royal road" to gather this information; you simply have to specify what commits you are interested in, and look at each of them, one by one.