# How to Replace a string pattern with another string pattern inside all files in directories and subdirectories

Tags: linux, shell, grep

I'm in the process of re-structuring my website & have to re-arrange references within files. There is a directory that contains many sub-directories & php files. I'm after some kind of a command/script that can search for each & every file in that directory for this pattern & replace it with a custom pattern.

For Eg: i want to replace exact occurrences of `one/two/three/`  by `/shopping/shop/ipad` . In other words if any file contains some string For Eg:

```
location:index.php?p=one/two/three/abcdefg&aid
```

then it should be replaced by

```
location:index.php?p=/shopping/shop/ipad/abcdefg&aid
```

Note the content replacement should take place inside every file, in every directory `/` sub directory within a main directory (say the main directory name is `abc` & all sub directories & files are within `abc`). The directory names themselves should not be changed. How can i achieve this ? My server runs linux & i have root & shell access.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
find . -type f|xargs perl -pi -e 's/one\/two\/three/shopping\/shop\/ipad/g'
```

tested and working fine.and it also doesnot replace if there is o
nly `one`

you can also find it [here](http://theunixshell.blogspot.in/2012/12/find-and-replace-string-in-all-files.html)

Answer (score 1):

`sed` is what you are looking for:

```
find .  -exec sed -i "s/one\/two\/three/shopping\/shop\/ipad/g" '{}' \;
```

Comment: this will replace `one` even if there's **just** `one`, and not `one/two/three`

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/one\/two\/three/shopping\/shop\/ipad/g'
```