# Is it possible to convert whole folder with convert-sass? (scss to sass)

Tags: css, sass

I have a bunch of files in bunch of folders in SCSS format. I need to convert it all to SASS format, and  I know sass has a specific command for that convert-sass, however I am not sure whether it is possible to convert whole folder (with folders inside)?

If its possible, then how convert-sass, else maybe there is a compiler who is able to do that? Thank you upfront:)

Comment: Do you actually need to convert?  You can mix and match sass and scss files in the same project.

Comment: I would prefer to convert, i want to modify all the files, plus I like it neat (that's why I am willing to go file by file in worst scenario)

Comment: If `convert-sass --help` doesn't provide information on how to do this, your best bet would be to ask "how do I run a command recursively over a directory of files in your terminal".

Comment: that is actually a good idea, if till tomorrow nobody will give more direct solution, i will use yours! thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Yes, `sass-convert` accepts a recursive argument.

If you run `sass-convert --help`, it will give you a list of available options. One of them is:

```
-R, --recursive      Convert all the files in a directory. Requires --from and --to.
```

So, your command should look like this:

```
sass-convert -R my_sass_dir --from sass --to scss
```

Comment: 2020 update - there is no `sass-convert` in Dart Sass (installed via npm), but we can access it by installing deprecated Ruby SASS - `gem install sass`.

Comment: Thank you @JakubZawiślak, I wasn't able to make it work through my global NPM but `gem install sass` worked for me, you saved my day.

Comment: how to remove old scss file in same cmd?

Answer (score 1):

#### Here's a slighly more extensive answer:

1. **go to your project subfolder, under which all your styles sit** (also, because you want to leave node_modules alone, do you?)

   `cd frontend/src`
2. **convert in place, as said** (consider `--indent 4` if that's your indentation style...)

   `sass-convert -R . --from scss --to sass --in-place`
3. **you almost certainly want to rename all those .scss files to .sass** [(details)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282/444255)

   `find . -name '*.scss' -exec sh -c 'mv "$0" "${0%.scss}.sass"'`
4. **In your .js or .jsx files, you want to adjust your import statements.**

   `find . -name '*.jsx' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i "s/'\.\(.*\)\.scss'/'.\1.sass'/g"`

   More specifically, only your *local* import statements, starting with a  '`.`', not your **global** imports, i.e. pointing to node_modules… right?

   **Testcase:**

   ```
   import './style.scss' // should change to .sass
   import './bar.scss'   // should change to .sass
   import 'slick-carousel/slick/slick.scss' // leave me alone!
   ```

**Remaining pitfalls are:**

- Your `webpack.config`s (loaders!), grunt or gulpfile, still matching against `.sass`
- global ‘common’ imports which you might prepend…