# How to overwrite the contents in the sed, without having backup file

Tags: macos, sed

I have a command like this:

```
sed -i -e '/console.log/ s/^\/*/\/\//' *.js
```

which does comments out all `console.log` statements. But there are two things

1. It keeps the backup file like `test.js-e` , I doesn't want to do that.
2. Say I want to the same process recursive to the folder, how to do it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have to use `-e` option in this particular case as it is unnecessary. This will solve your `1st` problem (as `-e` seems to be going as suffix for `-i` option).

For the `2nd` part, u can try something like this:

```
for i in $(find . -type f -name "*.js"); do sed -i '/console.log/ s/^\/*/\/\//' $i; done;
```

Use find to recursively find all `.js` files and do the replacement.

Comment: How comes that will work with a regex `^\/*` to match? won't that just match every line start (`^`)?

Comment: @armnotstrong: i didn't look at his expression btw... s/^/\/\//' would have been enough (comment out the mathcing line). He's using s/^\/*/\/\//' (see the * there.. => zero or more / at the beginning, which always evaluated to 0 / at beginning)

Comment: I presume that's not what the OP originally want to do. but He accept your answer, anyway, hope he knows what he is doing :-)

Answer (score 0):

When checking sed's help, `-i` takes a suffix and uses it as a backup,

> -i[SUFFIX], --in-place[=SUFFIX]
>                    edit files in place (makes backup if SUFFIX supplied)

and the output backup seems to be samefile + `-e` which is the second argument you're sending, try removing the space and see if that would work

```
sed -ie '/console.log/ s/^\/*/\/\//' *.js
```

As for the recursion, you could use `find` with `-exec` or `xargs`, please modify the find command and test it before running `exec`

```
find -name 'console.log' -type f -exec sed -ie '/console.log/ s/^\/*/\/\//' *.js \;
```

Answer (score 0):

From your original post I presume you just want to make a C-style comment leading like:

```
/*
```

to a double back-slash style like:

```
//
```

right?
Then you can do it with this command

```
find . -name "*.js" -type f -exec sed -i '/console.log/ s#^/\*#//#g' '{}' \;
```

To be awared that:

- in sed the split character normally be `/` but if you found that annoying to Escape when your replacing or matching string contains a `/` . You can change the split character to `#` or `|` as you like, I found it very useful trick.
- if you do want to do is what I presumed, be sure that you should Escape the character `*`, because a combination of regex `/*` just means to match a pattern that `/` occurs one time or many times or **none at all**, that will match everything, **it's very dangerous**!