# How to replace a string in multiple files using sed in unix?

Tags: unix

There are some 10 files say file a, file b, file c,...file j.
I have to search all these files and replace the string "xyz" with "abc".
Most important this has to be done with a shell script using for loop and sed command.can somebody provide the solution here

Comment: possible duplicate of [Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string)

Answer (score 9):

Use `sed`

```
sed -i s/xyz/abc/g files
```

- `-i` will edit the files in place
- `s///` will specify the substitution (read the manual for the details)
- `g` will replace more than one occurrence per line

for example

```
sed -i s/xyz/abc/g a b c d e f g h i j
```

or for all the files in the directory

```
sed -i s/xyz/abc/g *
```

Why a loop?