# Awk/Sed: How to do a recursive find/replace of a string in files with a certain file extension?

Tags: bash, replace, awk, sed

I need to recursively find and replace a string in my `.cpp` and `.hpp` files.

Looking at an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string) I've found the following command:

```
find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/subdomainA.example.com/subdomainB.example.com/g'
```

Changing it to include my file type did not work - did not changed any single word:

```
find /myprojects -type f -name *.cpp -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g'
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: You must _quote_ `*.cpp` - e.g., as `'*.cpp'` - to prevent premature expansion of the glob by the _shell_.

Comment: Hummm. still not working... `find /myprojects -type f -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g'`.

Comment: Isolate the problem by testing whether the `find` command itself works correctly, and test the `sed` command on a single file. Sometimes you get away with not quoting the glob - if the current dir. happens to contain no matches and `shopt -s nullglob` is not in effect - so it may not be the (only) source of the problem, but generally you should _always_ quote.

Comment: Also note that if you're on OS X / a BSD system, you must use `sed -i ''` instead of just `sed i`

Comment: I´m on Ubuntu... I´ve tested. `sed` expects the filename to be at the end of the command. I tried also `find /myprojects -type f -name '*.cpp' -print0 | xargs sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g' -0` with no success.. `sed -i s/word1/word2/g' file.cpp` works, `sed file.cpp -i s/word1/word2/g'` does not.... How to move the filename to the end of the `sed` command ?

Comment: You don't need to move the filenames to the end, because `xargs` places them there by default. If you quote `*.cpp`, there's nothing _conceptually_ wrong with your command, though @chepner's `-exec` solution below is preferable, albeit with `+` rather than `\;`.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in answering... I came back to this today and it´s working fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[chepner's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455554/45375) proposes the **simpler and more efficient use of `find`'s `-exec` action** instead of piping to `xargs`.

Unless special `xargs` features are needed, this change is always worth making, and maps to `xargs` features as follows:

- `find ... -exec ... {} \;` is equivalent to `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 -n 1 ...`
- `find ... -exec ... {} +` is equivalent to `find ... -print0 | xargs -0 ...`

In other words:

- the `\;` terminator invokes the target command once *for each matching file/folder*.
- the `+` terminator invokes the target command *once overall*, supplying  *all* matching file/folder paths as a single list of arguments.

  - Multiple calls happen only if the resulting command line becomes too long, which is rare, especially on Linux, where `getconf ARG_MAX`, the max. command-line length, is large.

---

**Troubleshooting the OP's command:**

Since the OP's `xargs` command passes all matching file paths *at once* - and per `xargs` defaults at the *end* of the command line, the resulting command will effectively look something like this:

```
  sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g' /myprojects/file1.cpp /myprojects/file2.cpp ...
```

This can easily be verified by prepending `echo` to `sed` - though (conceptual) quoting of arguments that need it (paths with, e.g., embedded spaces) will not show (note the `echo`):

```
find /myprojects -type f -name '*.cpp' -print0 | 
  xargs -0 echo sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g'
```

Next, after running the actual command, check whether the *last-modified date* of the files has changed using `stat`:

- If they have, yet the contents haven't changed, the implication is that `sed` *has* processed the files, but the regex in the `s` function call didn't match anything.

It is *conceivable* that older GNU `sed` versions don't work properly when combining `-i` (in-place editing) with *multiple* file operands (though I couldn't find anything in the [GNU `sed` release notes](https://github.com/bonzini/sed/blob/master/ChangeLog)).
To rule that out, invoke `sed` *once for each file*:

If you still want to use `xargs`, add `-n 1`:

```
 find /myprojects -type f -name '*.cpp' -print0 | 
   xargs -0 -n 1 sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g'
```

To use `find`'s `-exec` action, see [chepner's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33455554/45375).

---

With a GNU `sed` version that does support updating of *multiple* files with the `-i` option - which is the case as of *at least* v4.2.2 - the best formulation of your command is (note the quoted `*.cpp` argument to prevent premature expansion by the shell, and the use of terminator `+` to only invoke `sed` once):

```
find /myprojects -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g' '{}' +
```

Comment: The `echo` hint helped me to solve the issue, that was related to files structure. It indeed works !!! Thanks for helping!!!

Answer (score 4):

Don't bother with `xargs`; use the `-exec` primary. (Split across two lines for readability.)

```
find /home/www -type f -name '*.cpp' \
  -exec sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g' '{}' \;
```

Comment: Humm... I don´t think this is working, even correcting it: `find /home/www -type -f -name ' *.cpp' \ -exec sed -i 's/previousword/newword/g' '{}' +`...

Comment: @Mendez There's a space in your name pattern: `' *.cpp'`. It should be `'*.cpp'`.

Comment: Type error in so.... Your post has errors (souble `previousword` and missing + at the end)... But still does not work in Ubuntu...

Comment: @Mendez: There's another typo in your command: `-f` instead of `f`. While using `+` is _preferable_, because it will invoke `sed` only _once_ (typically), `\;` should work too. "Does not work" is not sufficient to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Ok about the typo, but is´t only a typo. "Does not work" means the given command `find /home/www -type f -name '*.cpp' -exec sed -i 's/word1/word2/g' '{}' +` searches the files but does not change its words as expected - the target .cpp and .hpp remains the same... `sed` as it is works in a single file if we put the filename at the end: `sed -i 's/word1/word2/g' file.cpp`. `find` works well showing all .cpp or .hpp files, but both together searches the files but does not change the texts as expected.

Comment: Typo? Your code: `'s/previousword/s/previousword/newword/g'`, I would expect `'s/previousword/newword/g'`. Including a warning about words with a `/`

Comment: I think I copied the `sed` command after starting to type it by hand. Fixing.