# How to update the value from app.config using Teamcity?

Tags: c#, selenium, teamcity

How to update/replace the value from app.config for different environment using Teamcity?
For Ex:
Consider below URL is for one environment. 
add key="URL" value="https://www.google.co.uk"

Now I want to update this value through Teamcity for different environment as:
add key="URL" value="https://www.google.co.in"

How can be done this using Teamcity?
Can anyone please guide me on this?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

Usually this kind of changes are done with [Add Config Transform](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465318(v=vs.100).aspx) in Visual Studio. Then you just build your project in different Configuration.

If you still want to do it in TeamCity, then you can use [File Content Replacer](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD10/File+Content+Replacer) in Build Features.

Answer (score 1):

As the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49148630/345659) mentioned you could do it with the File Content Replacer. However, this change is rolled back after the build is completed, [so it will not appear in your artifacts](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33669533/345659).

Instead I would recommend adding a new build step with a Powershell runner type. You can replace the code in there eg:
[image]