# Recursively replace a string while safely avoiding git directories

Tags: git, awk, sed, find

How can I replace all instances of `ABC` with `XYZ` in the current directory and all subdirectories?

In [this popular question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string) the top answers note that it's unwise to run commands like

```
find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/subdomainA\.example\.com/subdomainB.example.com/g'
```

in a folder containing `.git` directory, because the history can become corrupted.

How therefore can I do a replace in a folder that *does* have a `.git` directory in it? How's this?:

```
find /home/www/ -type f -not -path .git/ -exec \
    sed -i 's/ABC/XYZ/g' {} +
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to "prune" the `.git` directory.  Find's `-prune` directive always succeeds and, as a side effect, terminates search within the directory; and find's `or` operator is short-circuit, so:

```
find $top -name .git -prune -o -type f -print0 | xargs -0 ...
```

for instance.  This says: for each file, if the name is `.git` *and* `-prune` succeeds, we're done (and `-prune` did succeed and we don't descend into `.git`).  Otherwise, the name was not `.git`, so we do the "or" clause: if the type is "file", `-print0`.

Hence, this prints all the names of files that are not a `.git` directory, nor within a `.git` directory.  (Of course a `.git` directory is already also not a file, but we had to test for that to use `-prune`.)

Answer (score 1):

> In this popular question the top answers note that it's unwise to run commands like `find /home/www -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/ABC/ABX/g'` in a folder containing .git directory, because the history can become corrupted.

It's not just git directories, it's anything being used for software development.  Build products, databases, expected results from tests ... a command like that is begging for trouble.

```
git grep -lIz ABC | xargs -0 sed -i 's/ABC/DEF/g'
```

will get you just tracked text files, that's a decent start, and you can supply pathname patterns as well (e.g. `git grep foobar -- '*.[ch]'` shows all matching lines in tracked .c and .h files)