# How to change GO package alias en masse?

Tags: go

I want rename many packages across many files. At the same time, I also want to change package aliases. Is there any tool to do that? The ones I find in go/x/tools only change package imports.

I want to go from
import "github.com/a/b"

to

import b "github.com/c/d"

Comment: if you are on unix-like os then you could just use find+sed https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282/842075

Comment: Agreed with @MolecularMan on the sed approach

Answer (score 0):

There is a cool trick with std tools.

`gofmt` has an option `-r rule` which works like this:

`gofmt -w -l -r "github.com/a/b -> github.com/c/d" .`

where `rule` have format `pattern -> replacement`

See [gofmt docs](https://golang.org/cmd/gofmt/)

Also there is a `gofix` tool, but I haven't tried it, see [docs](https://golang.org/cmd/fix/) and [blog](https://blog.golang.org/introducing-gofix)

Comment: Thanks for sharing this cool trick! FWIW, I have written a python script to do basic search and replace. It does well enough to do the rest by hand. Here is my script: https://github.com/appscode/libbuild/blob/master/reimport.py