# How do I refactor module name in Go?

Tags: go, refactoring, go-modules

I have a Go module named `mymodule`, and I'd like to rename it into `github.com/hylowaker/awesome-module`

Using command `go mod edit -module github.com/hylowaker/awesome-module` only changes module name in `go.mod` file, leaving go sources unchanged. I tried Refactor feature in GoLand IDE, but GoLand does not allow renaming with slash(`/`) characters.

So I had to find and replace every `import "mymodule/..."` into `import "github.com/hylowaker/awesome-module/...` from my source files.

Is there a better way to refactor them?

Comment: This maybe a stupid comment, But wont a find and replace do the trick once you have edited it in go.mod ?

You can easily do a find and replace across project in Sublime or VSCode or Goland.

Comment: Like: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44548521/how-to-change-go-package-alias-en-masse?

Comment: @Kartavya I agree find&replace is enough for most cases, but since it could mistakenly replace comment or string as well, I was looking for safer and efficient way.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

This feature is introduced in GoLand version 2021.1.

You can invoke the Rename refactoring by pressing `Shift+F6` on the module name in the `go.mod` file.

Comment: You can also press `Shift+F6` on the package name in your `.go` file. (I'm using GoLand 2022.1.4)

Answer (score 5):

In GoLand just press Ctrl+Shift+R and execute "Replace in Path"

It is safe to perform that in entire project since you only need to change  go.mod file and all import clauses

Comment: great, on MacOS it is `cmd+shift+r`