# Replace complex c-variable in files

Tags: bash, sed

I need to replace a bunch of

```
 &p_Data->scratchBuffer0_U32[ 0 ]
```

with

```
 scratchBuffer0_U32
```

in a tons of c files in a directory and its sub-directories.

Also, some developers wrote the [ 0 ] as [0] and [ 0]

Answer (score 1):

This would be work:

```
find your_directory -name "*.c" | xargs sed -i 's/&\(p_Data->scratchBuffer0_U32\)[^]]*]/\1/g'
```

Comment: where does the output go in this cmd? Using the `-i` arg (assuming it is available), is the likely answer, but also risky until the O.P. tests for unintended consequences ;-) . Good luck to all.

Comment: @shellter Thanks, I forget to add the `-i` arg. I have updated my answer. :)

Comment: @electro I have updated me answer to match your need. Please let me know if it still goes wrong:)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using *nix and you are trying to replace a string in multiple files, check out this [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/awk-sed-how-to-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string) which shows you how to do a recursive replacement with find and perl.

As per the difference between the brackets, you'll have to run it for all 4 cases -- [0], [ 0], [0 ], and [ 0 ].

Answer (score 0):

With GNU sed for `-i` for pseudo-inplace editing:

```
find . -type f -exec sed -i 's/&p_Data->scratchBuffer0_U32\[[[:space:]]*0[[:space:]]*\]/scratchBuffer0_U32/g' {} +
```