# bash command doesn't work after quoting

Tags: bash

I'm trying to write a script to [recursively find & replace a string in a directory](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1583219/683218). But I wanted to exclude certain directories such as `.git/` from it.

In assembling a command string, the following command works if used directly (to replace `"F"` with `"R"`:

```
find . -not \( -path '.git' -prune \) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\"F\"/\"R\"/g'
```

But if I place the same thing in a string and then invoke it:

```
CMD="find . -not \( -path '.git' -prune \) -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i 's/\"F\"/\"R\"/g'"

$CMD
```

It fails with an error

```
find: paths must precede expression: \(
```

I've tried a few things with changing the quotes between single and double; and removing the `\` in `\(`. None works so far.

Does anyone know what went wrong and how to make the quoted command work?

Comment: This is [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050).

Answer (score -1):

You should try putting expression inside ``

Comment: That would string-split and glob-expand the output and execute it as a command itself. It doesn't fix the issue, but causes additional problems (or would, if there *were* any output rather than an error).