# Replace string in all files recursevely

Tags: recursion, github, rename, renaming

I have a private project called A I now want to call B. I can easily move the content from A to B, but how do I rename all content A to be now B? Specifically

```
const A = 1;
```

I want to replace that with

```
const B = 1;
```

In a smart way, where I replace all occurrences of A with B recursively?

Comment: The best solution is probably to use a language-specific refactoring tool. What language and editor or IDE are you using?

Comment: I am not using any IDE. Using gedit... Just thinking about deep replace of strings in multiple filles

Comment: Okay, what language? Replacing strings is error prone: consider `const A = 1;` vs. the string `'A'` or a string _containing_ `A` like `'A potato'`. (I know you're not literally wanting to replace `A`, but the challenge remains.) A language-aware refactoring tool that understands some level of semantics is going to do a better job. [It doesn't look like Gedit supports any](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Gedit/RequestedPlugins), but there may be standalone tools that you can use. Or you could briefly use a more powerful editor.

Comment: Well, it is a mix of js, php, md, sql and so on.  Just need a hint to recursively replace inside files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are sure about your expression to replace, you can try one of the solutions of "[How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583282/6309)"

Typically: a `find`followed with a `-exec sed -i`.

That would be enough to replace a *fixed* string by another.

Then add, commit and push back to your GitHub repo.

The [OP davidkonrad](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1407478/davidkonrad) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55698849/replace-string-in-all-files-recursevely/55700918#comment98136166_55700918):

> As a **case sensitive** search/replace within the directory:
>
> ```
> sudo find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/A/B/g' {} \;
> ```

Comment: Thank you, that headed me in the right direction. I have no clou about the `+` but after some attempts it actually worked out with `sudo find ./ -type f -exec sed -i -e 's/A/B/g' {} \;`  === **case sensitive** search/replace within the directory. There should be a GUI tool simplifying this to us newbies with only +15 yrs experience with Linux :)

Comment: @davidkonrad I agree. The "+" was short for "followed by". I will edit the answer to make that clearer, and to include your command.