# Remove closing PHP tags from all files

Tags: linux, sed, terminal

I am trying to find and remove all the closing PHP tags `?>` from the end of the PHP files on a website.

I have used:

```
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n 1 "$1" | grep -q "?>" && printf "%s\n" "$1"' -- {} \;
```

And this gives me a list of all the files that end with the PHP tag which is expected but the list is also over 500 files long so it would take a lot of time to manually go through.

I'm looking for a relatively easy way to do this if it is possible.

I've tried using `sed` like so:

```
 find . -type f -exec sh -c 'tail -n 1 "$1" | grep -q "?>" && printf "%s\n" "$1"' -- {} \; | sed -i '$ d' ./*
```

But this has two issues; it doesn't go into directories and it removes the last line from *all* files rather than just the ones that have the PHP closing tag.

I am expecting it to find all files with `?>` on the very last line (I can get this to work) and then delete that last line with the tag.

I feel like I'm quite close, just missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove last line that contains `?>` you may use

```
sed '${/?>/d;}'
```

The `'${/?>/d;}'` means:

- `$` - get the last line only
- `/?>/` - match the line only if it contains `?>` text
- `d` - delete the line.

To recursively run the sed command on a directory use

```
cd /your/dir/here && find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i '${/?>/d;}'
```

See more specific solutions for recursive file matching at [How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219)

Comment: I'm sorry, this doesn't seem to work. When I enter the command, it just takes me onto another line

Comment: @Ember No idea what you mean by "takes onto another line", the `sed` command [removes the last line if it contains `?>`](https://ideone.com/MJn84a)

Comment: Sorry, I should have been clearer in my comment. When I press enter in the terminal, nothing appears to happen and the cursor in the terminal just moves onto the next line

Comment: I have managed to get it working in one directory at a time but it does not go into any sub-directories

Comment: @Ember That is a solved issue please refer to [How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219)

Comment: Tried `cd /your/dir/here && find . -type f -print0 |  xargs -0 sed -i '${/?>/d;}'` yet?

Comment: That seems to work! Thank you, I was having a look at the question you linked but I'm sadly not that terminal savvy (I'm learning). I'll just run a few more tests with that before I accept the answer to double check everything works as expected (I'm sure it will).