# Run Regex using Grep/Sed recursively over files to store capture group

Tags: regex, bash, sed, grep

I have a file structure that looks like this:

> - Folder1
>
>   - file1.feature
>   - file2.feature
>   - file3.feature
> - Folder2
>
>   - file1.feature
>   - file2.feature
>   - ...etc.

The files are Behat feature files which look like this:

```
Scenario: I am filling out a form
    Given I am logged in as User
    And I fill in "Name" with "My name"
    Then I fill in "Email" with "myemail@example.com"
```

I am trying to iterate over each file within the file structure to get matches on my regex:

```
/I fill in "[^"]+" with "([^"]+)"/gm
```

The regex looks for I fill in "x" with "y", and I would like to store the capture group "y" from each file where a line in the file matches the expression.

So far I can iterate through the folders and print out the file names in mt Bash script like so:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd behat/features

files="*/*.feature"


for f in $files
do
    echo ${f}
done
```

I am trying to retrieve the capture group using Sed currently by doing this in my loop:

```
sed -r 's/^I fill in \"[^)]+\" with \"([^)]+)\"$/\1/'
```

But I fear that I am going down the wrong track, as this is returning all of the file content throughout all the files.

Comment: Try `sed -E -n 's/.*I fill in "[^"]+" with "([^"]+)"/\1/p'`, see [this demo](https://ideone.com/wqAJ4r)

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew sweet, that works on when I run it on an individual file, do you know how I could incorporate this into my script please?

Comment: `cd behat/features && find . -name *.feature -type f -print0 | xargs -0 sed -E -n 's/.*I fill in "[^"]+" with "([^"]+)"/\1/p' > outfile`?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew dude, thank you!! Post it as an answer and I can accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
cd behat/features && find . -name *.feature -type f -print0 | xargs -0 \
  sed -E -n 's/.*I fill in "[^"]+" with "([^"]+)"/\1/p' > outfile
```

This command "goes" to `behat/features` directory, finds all files with `feature` extension (recursively) and then prints the capture group #1 values matched with your regex as `-n` option suppresses the output of lines and `p` flag only outputs what remains after a replacement.

See more specific solutions for recursive file matching at [How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219) if need be.