# Removing .html URLs with GREP & XARGS

Tags: regex, command-line, grep, wget, xargs

I am using WGET to burn a static copy of a PHP website. I would like to remove all references to *.html* in every `<a href` for every file. So any link for example, `<a href="path/project-name.html">Project Name</a>`, I would like changed to `<a href="path/project-name">Project Name</a>`.

The command `grep -rl index.html . | xargs sed -i 's/index.html//g'` works great at removing every *index.html* in all the links.

But I can't get it to work for every *.html* link with the command `grep -rl *.html . | xargs sed -i 's/*.html//g'`.

Any assistance with my regex would be much appreciated.

Comment: `'s/*.html//g'` is wrong since you entered a glob pattern in the LHS, where a regex pattern is expected. What is the pattern you want to match?

Comment: Thanks, @wiktor. So any link for example, `<a href="path/project-name.html">Project Name</a>`, I would like changed to `<a href="path/project-name">Project Name</a>`.

Comment: Try `grep -rl *.html . | xargs sed -i -E 's/(href="[^"]*)\.html"/\1"/g'`

Answer (score 1):

`'s/*.html//g'` is wrong since you entered a glob pattern in the LHS (left hand side part of the `sed` substitution command), where a regex pattern is expected.

You can use

```sh
grep -rl *.html . | xargs sed -i -E 's/(href="[^"]*)\.html"/\1"/g'
```

*Details*:

- `-E` - the option that enables the POSIX ERE regex syntax
- `(href="[^"]*)\.html"` - matches and captures into Group 1 (later, accessed via `\1` backreference) a `href="` substring and any zero or more chars other than `"` after, and then just matches `.html` substring
- `\1"` - replaces with Group 1 and a `"` char
- `g` - all non-overlapping occurrences on a line.

Comment: So this works and does remove the .html extension from all HREF links but for some reason, this isn't recursively going through every sub directory.

Comment: @spencerthayer Try `find . -type f -name '*.html' -print0 | xargs -0 sed -i -E 's/(href="[^"]*)\.html"/\1"/g'`, see [How to do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1583229/3832970).