# Make sed replace in files recursively

Tags: bash

I need to replace `Android` in my C++ string literals with `Windows`. The command below probably prints updated source code:

```
find . -name *.cpp -type f | xargs sed -E 's/"(.*)Android(\s.*)"/\1Windows\2/'
```

How to make it update found files?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/159367/using-sed-to-find-and-replace

Comment: All Unix commands have manual pages. Type `man sed`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I do a recursive find/replace of a string with awk or sed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1583219/how-can-i-do-a-recursive-find-replace-of-a-string-with-awk-or-sed) Also, please read over these [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) for asking a good question. I used only the most cursory terms from your own title to do a search that found this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use the `-i` option in `sed` to perform in-place editing

in Linux or GNU-based systems, you can use the `-i` option without any argument

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -type f | xargs sed -i -E 's/"(.*)Android(\s.*)"/\1Windows\2/'
```

but in macOS or BSD-based systems, you can use the `-i ''` option:

```
find . -name "*.cpp" -type f | xargs sed -i '' -E 's/"(.*)Android(\s.*)"/\1Windows\2/'
```